# how to get Bluetooth name of peer device in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-bluetooth

how is it possible to get the `Bluetooth` information (name, Mac address,...) of the peer device that the android device is connected to that via `Bluetooth` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to get all remote devices :)

```
private void discoveryDevice(){
// Register the BroadcastReceiver
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);

    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter); // Don't forget to unregister during onDestroy

    mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
}

// Create a BroadcastReceiver for ACTION_FOUND
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        // When discovery finds a device
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

            Log.d(TAG, "device " + device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
        }
    }
};
```

It's really good for you to get the name of remote device throught the code:

```
Log.d(TAG, "device " + device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't test this code at this moment but maybe can give an idea to how you can get the name and others parameters of bluetooth.

```
 static BluetoothSocket socket ;
 public static boolean btCon(Context ctx){

 Method m;
 try {
      BluetoothDevice devc = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getRemoteDevice(MAC_ADRS);

      m = devc.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[]{int.class});
      socket = (BluetoothSocket)m.invoke(devc, Integer.valueOf(1));
  socket.connect();

   String name = devc.getName();/* or */ String name2 = devc.getName().toString();
       Log.i("Test","Name: "+name); 
       Log.i("Test","Name 2: "+name2); 

  return true;
 }catch(Exception e)
 {
  return false;
 }
}
```